# How can I enable case-insensitive search on openGauss

Tags: open-gauss

How can I enable case-insensitive search on openGauss ? My fields are all uppercase when creating the tables, and when searching, it is converted to lowercase and causes failure.

```
SELECT XH,QYBH from user
Error info： No xh column found
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with openGauss, but in most other RDBMS that would be controlled by a server or database-scoped `COLLATION` option, if that helps...

Comment: I don't use openGauss either, but - would enclosing identifiers into double quotes do any good? For example, `select "XH", "QYBH" from user`

Answer (score 0):

The column names in openGauss will be case-sensitive if the column name was enclosed in double quotes when defining it, otherwise they will be case-insensitive. When you run a SELECT query unquoted column names are automatically converted to lower-case. As a result, if a column name is case-sensitive you need to wrap the name in double quotes.

Here are some examples:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ("COLA" int, "COLB" int);
SELECT "COLA","COLB" FROM t1; -- works
SELECT cola,colb FROM t1; -- does not work
SELECT COLA,COLB FROM t1; -- does not work
```

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (COLA int, COLB int);
SELECT cola,colb FROM t2; -- works 
SELECT COLA,COLB FROM t2; -- works
SELECT CoLa,cOLb FROM t2; -- works
SELECT "cola","colb" FROM t2; -- works
SELECT "cola","colb" FROM t2; -- does not work
```